# Ruby Tk entry widget will not update textvariable

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to write a GUI in Ruby using TK for a Mad Libs program. Essentially, it needs to take the user's input from an Entry widget and replace certain words in a line of text with that information. 
The following is the relevant code ($content is the parent window):

```
$name=TkVariable.new()
name=Tk::Tile::Entry.new($content) {width 7; textvariable $name}.grid(:column =>1, :row  =>0, :sticky => 'we')
# Mad Lib base text
$text=TkVariable.new("My name is #{name.get}.")

# Displays end result
def showResult
display=Tk::Tile::Label.new($content) {textvariable $text}.grid(:column =>0, :row     => 6, :sticky => 'we')
end

# Button to replace input in base text.
# Clicking this button adds a new Label widget containing the text. The variables,
#however, retain whatever value they were initialized to (in this case, nothing)
Tk::Tile::Button.new($content) {text 'Submit'; command 'showResult'}.grid(:column => 1,     :row => 5, :sticky => 'we')
```

As I understand, name.get should give me whatever I've entered into the Entry widget's field. Yet neither name nor $name updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text variables don't work this way. It appears you are trying to embed one textvariable into another. When you do `"My name is #{name.get}."`, it gets the value of the `name` variable *at  the time this statement is executed*, it won't dynamically update.

If you want an entry widget and label to be kept in sync, they need to share the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try....

```
def showResult
   $text.value = "My name is #{name.get}."
   display=Tk::Tile::Label.new($content) {textvariable $text}.grid(:column =>0, :row     =>    6, :sticky => 'we')
end
```

this should update the variable each time showResult is called
but not entirely sure with Entry boxes

this is how I update my TkVariables